# Match first word at the beginning of a line (Vim)

Tags: regex, vim

**Example:**

```
# Objects:
math =
  root: Math.sqrt
  square: square
  cube: (x) -> x * square x

# Splats:
race = (winner, runnners...) ->
  print winner, runners
```

I want to match `cube` and `race` (variables/objects that store functions).

I realized I can't use `^\w` because it won't match the words with a space behind, like `cube`.

What regex should I use in this case?

Comment: Why just `cube` and `race`, how are they related? Why not `math,root,square,print`?  Your mention of `^\w` makes it confusing.

Comment: based on the current revision of question and the example, I would say `/cube\|race`

Comment: @Michael Berkowski they are, I don't know what to call them, they are the variables/objects that store functions.

Comment: If you're happy to include leading whitespace `^\s*\w\w*` will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your current example, this pattern would find those text:

```
/\zs\S\+\ze\s*[:=]\s*(
```

it matches text, which followed by any number of spaces and a `:` or `=` then any number of spaces, then a `(`.  I hope this is what you are looking for.

I used `\S\+` instead of `\w` because I don't kown if char like `-, # etc.` also could be used as variable name.

Comment: Sorry, still not matching `cube`.

Comment: @alexchenco in my vim, it does.

Comment: Oh, it does now. Thanks, could you add a brief explanation? I would check your answer as correct then.

Comment: I added @alexchenco which part you still have problem to understand?

Comment: it's OK it's clear. I'll check it as correct thanks.

Comment: You do not need the `\zs` so it can be reduced to `\S\+\ze\s*[:=]\s*(`