# Why isn't the following regex working with the following modifications (Vim)?

Tags: regex, vim

I asked this question a few hours ago: [Match first word at the beginning of a line (Vim)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323612/match-first-word-at-the-beginning-of-a-line-vim/28323830?noredirect=1#comment44995531_28323830).

To match the fist word at the beginning of a line that's before `:=` and `(` :

```
\S\+\ze\s*[:=]\s*(
```

Then I turned it into a very magic version:

```
\v\S+\ze\s*[:=]\s*\(
```

Everything OK. The problem arised when I changed the `(` charactor to an `->` character:

```
/\v\S+\ze\s*[:=]\s*\-\>
```

It says "Pattern not found", doesn't match anything.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex matches only when `->` follows `:` or `=` immediately (modulo whitespace).

However, given your [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323612/match-first-word-at-the-beginning-of-a-line-vim/28323830), you're applying the regex to some sort of function definition whose syntax includes the signature ( ie. list of function argments + syntactic sugar ). Therefore in order to match your regex must cater for the signature part, effectively skipping it. Assuming that `-` is not a valid character within the signature part, the following modified regex will do the trick:

```
/\v\S+\ze\s*[:=][^\-]+\-\>
```

The difference to the original is the additional `[^\-]+` part which skips over the function signature ( `-` of `->` serves as a blocker here ).

Note that `-` does not need to be escaped when listed as the last item in a regex character class ( ... but i have developed the [bad?] habit of doing it anyway as it comes handy when modifying or copy-pasting the regex ...).